# C# Form closes and reopens, throws "cannot access a disposed object"

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a button that starts a new form, and this button runs a async task. When I close the form and click the button again, it throws "cannot access a disposed object". Here is the pseudocode.

```
private async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await work();
}

private async Task work()
{
    form.show();
    while(true)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => sendData(data1, data2)); // this just sends some data to the new form
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

The second form simply displays the data sent. I do not need this to run in background when the form is closed. I am new to async method, so not sure how to get around this problem..

Comment: You `Show` your form in your `work` method. When you close the form, you should consider the form object _all used up_; `Close` on a Windows Forms form `Disposes` The form and anything on the form. It can't be Shown again.. The solution is to create a new Form object and show that. If you want to persist state between firm showings, create a separate object that lives longer than the form and that you pass to the form at construct-time (or perhaps Show-time)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: `await Task.Run(async () => sendData(data1, data2));`? I doubt it. Where's the `await` part? Are you trying to `async` a sync method? You already have `Task.Run()` there... -- `while(true)` and you allow to press the Button again? This code needs a lot of care before it can actually do something useful for you.

Comment: Could you include the `sendData` method in the question? Be aware that the `Task.Run` invokes the delegate on the `ThreadPool`, and accessing UI components is allowed only on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close the form it gets dispose.  You need to initialize a new form in your worker.

```
private async Task work()
{
    Form form = new Form();
    form.Show()
    while(true)
    {
    await Task.Run(async () => sendData(data1, data2)); // this just sends some data to the new form
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it. I initialized the form outside of the method.. such a simple thing to overlook....